# Insert a line before/after a row during drag&drop in listview

Tags: vb.net, listview, drag-and-drop

I would like to show a blue line during drag&drop in a single listview. This should help to recognize if the dragged row will be dropped before or after the actual row. *(The other needed events like .DragEnter, .DragDrop are working as expected).*

How can I draw such a blue line in VB.NET without 3rd party listview controls?
So far, I found the event "GiveFeedback":

```
Sub listView1_GiveFeedback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GiveFeedbackEventArgs) Handles listView1.GiveFeedback
    e.UseDefaultCursors = False
    Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = Cursors.Cross

    '<--- Show the blue insertion line until row is dropped

End Sub
```

Could somebody please show me the missing code for a blue insertion line?

Comment: You should show what you have tried. The code you are showing does not represent almost anything within what is required (also, not sure about the point of using this event). You need to track the exact position where the element is dropped and come up with the format change of the specific item in the ListView.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, for pointing me in the right direction! I found the desired solution in a .DragOver Event:

```
Sub ListView1_DragOver(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles ListView1.DragOver
    Dim MousePointerCoordinates As Point = ListView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
    Dim RowIndex As Integer = ListView1.InsertionMark.NearestIndex(MousePointerCoordinates)
    ListView1.InsertionMark.Index = RowIndex
End Sub
```

The Color for the line itself is defined in the form.load with

```
ListView1.InsertionMark.Color = Color.Blue
```

Answer (score 1):

This should hopefully point you in the right direction:

First, set `ListView1.OwnerDraw = True`

then add the following:

```
Private Sub ListView1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.DrawItem
    e.DrawDefault = True

    'Do checks here if drag
    Dim Pos As Point = Me.ListView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)

    If Me.ListView1.GetItemAt(Pos.X, Pos.Y) Is e.Item Then
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top, e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Top)
    End If

End Sub
```

Please note this is rough, and you will need to add in code to check if drag is taking place. You would also need to Invalidate the listview (or at least the listviewitem's region) when moving the mouse.

I recommend you look at creating a new class that inherits from listview, as this will make it a lot easier to manage your code

Hope this helps point you in the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like this, but a bit different. What I wanted to achieve was to draw a line but depending on the position of the index, the line should be drawn before or after a specific item.

Example: I got a list view with 5 items.

- Scenarion 1: Move item 4 to position 2. The line is drawn before item 2.
- Scenarion 2: Move item 1 to position 5. The line is drawn after item 5.

And this is the code I have used to achieve this:

```
Private Sub lvDisplayed_DragOver(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles lvDisplayed.DragOver
    Dim MousePointerCoordinates As Point = Me.lvDisplayed.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
    Dim RowIndex As Integer = lvDisplayed.InsertionMark.NearestIndex(MousePointerCoordinates)
    Me.lvDisplayed.InsertionMark.AppearsAfterItem = Me.lvDisplayed.SelectedIndices(0) <= RowIndex
    Me.lvDisplayed.InsertionMark.Index = RowIndex
End Sub
```

And you will also need to set the **InsertionMark.Color** , I've set it in **NEW**.

```
Me.lvDisplayed.InsertionMark.Color = Color.DarkRed
```

Hope this helps as I looked for something like this a lot.